# Slow performance when using find dialog in Microsoft Access with SQL Server backend

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I've recently completed a migration of an Access database to SQL Server 2014.

In the Access front end I've updated all the forms and most of the reports to work with SQL Server. Everything works well and I see better performance pretty much across the board as one would expect.

However, there is one problem I can't seem to find an answer to anywhere. My user uses the Access 'Find and Replace' dialog box to find a specific record out of a measly ~2100 with the Access DB this was nearly instant. With the SQL Server database, this takes over 30 seconds to complete and freezes Access.

I've noticed in the SQL Server Activity Monitor that the Batch Requests/sec spikes when you use the find, but other than that I have no way of knowing what Access is actually doing behind the scenes to perform the find out of the 'Find and Replace' dialog box or how to resolve it.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: You could use SQL Profiler to monitor what's going on in the background. Since 'find and replace' is not a native sql function, I guess it is doing something horribly inefficient. You might have to write your own using stored procedures and forms if you can narrow down it's usage to  particular cases

Answer (score 1):

That `Find & replace` performs on Row-By-Row basis. So, you have as many single updates as many `search` matching values you have.

I'd rather not use `linked tables`, but rather `Pass-Through` queries through a form. Then users will see the data and you can program a functionality to `find and replace` by SQL command in bulk, which will be very quick.

Comment: Thanks for the info Slava, it's too bad they don't give you a way to modify the query that the default find dialog uses.  My user will have to get used to not using ctrl + f to pull up the default find dialog and start using the custom one I build!  oh joy...

Comment: That was written for MS Access. You can link a table to many different sources and it will work. If you want to make it faster with SQL Server, you have to out your hands in.

Comment: Creating a Pass-Through query and linking the form to that (instead of the ODBC linked table) increased find performance from 5-10 seconds to instantaneous on my small data set of 2100 records. However Pass-Through queries are non-updatable and cannot be used in subforms.

Comment: You have to try it. You can pass "`UPDATE table Set ABC = 'XYZ' WHERE A = 'B';`" as pass-through query